# Hung Gar institutions

Tags: kung-fu

[Hung Gar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hung_Gar) (洪家) has its roots in China. It has spread to many countries, but the curriculum varies from school to school, and the connection to China is of varying quality. In mainland China the style may have been influenced by the development of [Wushu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wushu_%28sport%29) after 1949.

Has the style been changed much by standardization through Wushu? Are there still dedicated schools, or is the best option to start studying Wushu?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to look at our [FAQ](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq).  This question is very narrowly focused in both time and location, making it difficult to answer and for helping others.  If you can edit it so that it is a little broader (e.g., more about what you are looking for and more detail about the styles you are considering) then it can be easily reopened.

Comment: Sorry! Should have read the FAQ better. Made some changes, and added more details. Hope it is not still too localized.

Comment: Ok, removed most of the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hung Gar has very little connection to wushu. It is not nearly as flashy, and puts a heavy emphasis on body conditioning and low stances to build a strong fighter, as opposed to wushu, which emphasizes gymnastic ability and flexibility.

Comment: Wushu is sometimes promoted like it represents everything that is Chinese martial art, and said to draw from styles like Hung Gar. But it sounds like there is no such thing like a complete Hung Gar form available within the Wushu curriculum? Then, what are the best sources for Hung Gar?

Comment: find a school that fights in *full contact* lei tai and/or sanda matches (and not those silly point sparring and "medium contact" tournaments, either.) stick with the full contact fighters, those schools have better kung fu.